SSRS report column chart show data labels position in the middle
Would like to Position the data label in the middle of the column chart
Current Chart
I tried to change the property of the data label position to Top, Middle, bottom. It only stay on the top of the column.
Property setting
Would like the final result like this
Thank you for your help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community - they are asking about the Chart Label properties - which don;t work the way they should.

Unfortunately, the chart's Position property doesn't work the way it should, nor the way you think it does. The position is actually in relation to the top of the bar, not the whole bar - so Center would put the label in the middle of the top of the bar.
The closest you can come is Bottom which would put it at the bottom of the top of the bar.

Click on the Chart Series (or a bar) and change the Chart Series' Custom Attributes Label Style to Bottom.

